# Does tx:annotation-driven respect beans imported and does the order of service import matter?

Tags: spring, transactions, import, annotations

Hi i have a following question.

According to spring docs tx:annotation-driven only respects bean definition that it is define in.

However i have the following code

```
<import resource="applicationContext-service1.xml"/>
<import resource="applicationContext-service2.xml"/>
<import resource="applicationContext-service3.xml"/> 
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

" only looks for @Transactional on beans in the same application context it is defined in. This means that, if you put ".

I have beans definte in service1, 2, 3 ...

1.) Do I actually have to add tx:annotation-driven to applicationContext-service1.xml ... etc. 
2.) Does the order of import resource matter for transaction boundary creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application context is not an XML file. All the beans declared in the imported files are part of the same application context. And the order doesn't matter.